# Is it possible to add a color picker or a hex field to WooCommerce attribute to make it similar to color swatch without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a multilingual WooCommerce shop using the WPML plugin. All of **my products are variable products** not simple. I have created WooComerce attributes like (size, brand, and color) that I use for filtration on the shop page.

What I'm trying to achieve is that "I want to extend the WooCommerce variable color attribute by adding a color picker or even a simple field to add my hex color code to it, so it will be showing on the shop page as a color not just a name for a better user experience" similar to color swatches but **without the use of any plugins at all**.

So from the WooComerce attributes page, a color picker or a field to accept my #hex value will be added.

[image]

To achieve this look on the shop page.

[image]

I have been looking for a solution for this functionality all over the internet **without the use of a plugin** but I couldn't find any even though I have developed some CSS rules for achieving that but I know it's not the best approach since I need to add a rule for each color and it uses the (*) which is slow and not recommended.

```
a[href*="filter_color=reds"]{
    background-color: #cc1818;
    font-size: 0;
}

a[href*="filter_color=creams"]{
    background-color: #d5b49f;
    font-size: 0;
}

a[href*="filter_color=blacks"]{
    background-color: #2f3032;
    font-size: 0;
}

... etc for all colors even if I have n.
```

So can I achieve this through code? or even without the need to create the color picker or #hex value field and use a different approach like target the label of that color?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check sity by Misha Rudrastyh.https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/display-variations-with-color-or-size-buttons.html. Maybe you can do something similar as a function.

```html
$attribute_type = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT attribute_type
            FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
            WHERE attribute_name = '%s'
            ",
            substr( $taxonomy, 3 ) // remove "pa_" prefix
        )
    );
```